SQLAlchemy relationship warning
I've book, author and section model with relationship and I'm getting a warning:

SAWarning: relationship 'Section.books' will copy column section.id to column book_section.section_id, which conflicts with relationship(s): 'Section.sections' (copies section.id to book_section.section_id). If this is not the intention, consider if these relationships should be linked with back_populates, or if viewonly=True should be applied to one or more if they are read-only. For the less common case that foreign key constraints are partially overlapping, the orm.foreign() annotation can be used to isolate the columns that should be written towards.   To silence this warning, add the parameter 'overlaps="sections"' to the 'Section.books' relationship. (Background on this warning at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/qzyx) (This warning originated from the configure_mappers() process, which was invoked automatically in response to a user-initiated operation.)

Here is the  code:
class Author(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "author"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(256), nullable=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now(timezone.utc))

from datetime import datetime, timezone

from src.db import db

book_author = db.Table(
    "book_author",
    db.Column(
        "book_id",
        db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey("book.id"),
        primary_key=True,
    ),
    db.Column(
        "author_id",
        db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey("author.id"),
        primary_key=True,
    ),
)

book_section = db.Table(
    "book_section",
    db.Column(
        "book_id",
        db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey("book.id"),
        primary_key=True,
    ),
    db.Column(
        "section_id",
        db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey("section.id"),
        primary_key=True,
    ),
)


class Book(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "book"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(512), nullable=False)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    yop = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)  # Year of publication
    authors = db.relationship(
        "Author",
        secondary=book_author,
        backref=db.backref("book", lazy="dynamic"),
    )
    sections = db.relationship(
        "Section",
        secondary=book_section,
        backref=db.backref("sections", lazy="dynamic"),
        lazy="dynamic",
    )
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now(timezone.utc))



class Section(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "section"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now(timezone.utc))
    description = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=True)
    books = db.relationship(
        "Book",
        secondary="book_section",  # Assuming 'book_section' is the correct association table
        back_populates="sections",
        lazy="select",  # Or use 'subquery' depending on your use case
    )

How can I avoid this warning?

Unless it's serving a specific purpose, I would change backref=db.backref("sections", lazy="dynamic") to back_populates="books".
